# How to display the value of a javascript object in the form of a combination of numbers and letters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, key

My object of javascript like this :

```
{
    "container_status": {
        "name": "/dev-ms",
        "port": {
            "2233/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostPort": "123"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display value of key HostPort

I try like this :

```
console.log(data.container_status.port.2233/tcp[0].HostPort
```

But it does not works

There exist error : `Unexpected token, expected`

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square bracket like this `['2233/tcp']`. This is because `/` in name object name is invalid unless use dot notation is used

`2233/tcp` will be an invalid object name

```js
let data = {
  "container_status": {
    "name": "/dev-ms",
    "port": {
      "2233/tcp": [{
        "HostPort": "123"
      }]
    }
  }
}

console.log(data.container_status.port['2233/tcp'][0].HostPort)
```